# How to access a private List object of another object for testing in java

Tags: java, junit

I'm facing to a similar kind of scenario as described below. Since I'm unable to share the actual code I'm using that.

I'm trying to test the `addToList()` method in the below class.

```
public class MyClass{

    private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addToList(String name){
        nameList.add(name);
    }
}
```

I want to check whether the list get updated by calling the `addToList()` method. (`nameList.size()` check is enough)

I'm writing JUnits and can't figure out a way to access that `nameList` after calling the method.

```
   @Test
   public void test() {
      MyClass my = new MyClass();
      my.addToList("one");
      my.addToList("two");

      // how to check the 'nameList' to complete the test
   }
```

May be Reflections can be the solution for this, but still it is unclear.

What is the best way to do that (without changing the actual class).

Comment: And hint: the reasonable way is **not** reflection; but to use dependency injection to **provide** a list to your class under test.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: You got a lot of information in that linked DUP question; and google has a lot of hits for such terms, such as http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200709/dependency-injection-unit-testing.html